# jquery - reverting back to original style declarations after .css() call, and other weirdness

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a status bar in my web app grow when it receives a message (via php) and then revert back to it's original height after a few seconds.

Here's the css that is applied when the page is loaded:

```
<style>

      #status {

        height:17px;
        background-color:#424242;
        -moz-transition:height 1s;
        -webkit-transition:height 1s;

        }

    #status:hover {

        height:60px;

     }

</style>
```

and here is the code that is called when the user receives a message.

```
<script>

    $('#status').css('height', '60px');
    $('#status_message').text('$message').show();
    $('#status').delay(1000).css('height', '17px');

 </script>
```

However, I'm having two problems. One, everything works when I take out the last statement in the script, so I think the delay() call is messing something up. I've tried moving it to the end of the second statement like this:

```
<script>

    $('#status').css('height', '60px');
    $('#status_message').text('$message').show().delay(100000);
    $('#status').css('height', '17px');

 </script>
```

But that also doesn't work. The second problem I'm having is one the above code runs, then the original css hover event for my status bar doesn't work. I've tried re-specifyng all of the original css for the status bar with the $.css() function, but it still doesn't work. I think it has something to do with me not being able to re-apply the #status:hover event with jQuery, and when I try to implement the same behavior with .hover() , it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, what about the hover event doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use a `setTimeout`?

```
setTimeout(function()
{
     $('#status').css('height': '17px');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I got hover to work, I was chaining it improperly. Also, your code ran after I replaced ':' with a ','. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is that using .css through jquery actually applies an inline style.

to avoid this, put the new css in a new class, for example:

```
#status.dynamic{
    height:60px;
}
```

and your js:

```
    $('#status').addClass('dynamic');
    //$('#status_message').text('$message').show().delay(100000);
    $('#status').removeClass('dynamic');
```

as for the delay, you aren't delaying anything by putting it last. if you want to see it work, try it like:

```
$('#status_message').text('$message').show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
```